# Xbox Does Elite Dangerous Horizons cover multiple users

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

I just purchased Elite Dangerous for my xbox, and it comes with a redeem code for Elite Dangerous Horizons. If I redeem it on one Xbox live account, can I still use it on a different Xbox account?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out myself, and Elite Dangerous: horizons season pass does game sharing on the xbox one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will be account-bound to whatever account redeems it, like most other XBL purchases.

I can also confirm that, at least when it launched, *Horizons* did not game share to other users on your "Home" console.

Comment: What about if one account has that xbox as it's home xbox?

Comment: @FinnShadow i put that in my answer actually, home sharing did not work for horizons at launch, not sure if its changed since then (most likely not) but its impossible for me to test